# Facebook pay.prompt callback fails in IE with wmode=window

Tags: facebook, flash, internet-explorer

My Flash app calls:

Facebook.ui("pay.prompt", data, onPayCallback, "iframe");

which works correctly on all browsers, until a recent change in the embedding of the swf file. I now use wmode="window" which gives much better performance in IE (previously I used "opaque").

When the facebook credits popup appears, the game is now hidden as expected. It returns correctly when the popup is closed. However, on IE (version 9, other versions are untested) the callback is never called.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

Did you manage to get any further on this?

In my case the javascript callback is triggered, and the call to the flash function is also being made, but throws an error "Object required".. with a little bit more digging (using IE's developer tool) the addcallBack function in the swf was null..